# Organize data sent between client-server

Tags: python, sockets, python-2.7

Pardon me if this has been addressed before, but how do I organize data exchanged between client and server in python application (sockets)?

Let's say I have some elements I have to send - strings, tuples, dicts:

```
"hello world", (1, 2, 3), {"k": "v"}
```

What I currently do is I simply convert everything to string - call `repr()` before sending and `eval()` after receiving. This obviously seem a bit redundant.

How should I send these chunks of data? Is there a convention? Preferred format? How do I compress it?

Comment: if you're looking for a term to google, this is 'serialization' and python has `pickle` for python->python exchanges and `json` for python->world exchanges.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to [pickle](http://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#module-pickle) them on the client side and unpickle them on the server side. However, to need to ensure that the data is coming from a trusted source as it is possible to force unpickle to execute arbitrary code. Make sure you use `cPickle` to get the C language implementation.

Answer (score 3):

JSON is what you're looking for. If you have an object and you import the JSON functions:

```
from json import dumps, loads
```

you can use `dumps(obj)` to encode into JSON and `loads(str)` to convert a JSON string back to an object. For example:

```
dumps([[1,2,3],{"a":"b", "c":"d"}])
```

yields `'[[1, 2, 3], {"a": "b", "c": "d"}]'` and

```
loads('[[1, 2, 3], {"a": "b", "c": "d"}]')
```

yields `[[1, 2, 3], {u'a': u'b', u'c': u'd'}]`.

Answer (score 1):

You should [***never*** `eval()` data from an untrusted source](http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html), which means you should never `eval()` anything arriving over an unsecured network connection (or where you can't be absolutely certain the entity at the other end is who or what it says it is).

The obvious solution here is to [encode the data as JSON](http://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html) at one end, and decode it at the other (unless you have specific performance requirements that require a highly-compressed format like e.g [msgpack](http://msgpack.org/)).